# Discord.js multiple reaction collector

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How do I make this code work with multiple reactions?
I would like the embed to have multiple reactions, and based on the selected reaction, it would give a different response
Here's the code:

````
module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    description: "ping command",
    async execute(message, args, Discord){
        
        var newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#A5775C')
        .setTitle('Reactions')
        .setDescription('*React to this!')
        
const MAX_REACTIONS = 1;
        
      const sentMessage = await message.channel.send({embeds: [newEmbed]});

      await sentMessage.react('');

      const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && !user.bot;

      const collector = sentMessage.createReactionCollector({
        filter,
        max: MAX_REACTIONS,
      });

      collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {

        if (reason === 'limit')
          return message.channel.send(`You reacted with !`);
      });
    }
  }```
````

Comment: You should probably describe in detail what you really want to achieve. And why do you set `MAX_REACTIONS` to `1` if you want to handle more than one reaction?

Comment: i want it to be kind of like a multiple choice question where there are multiple reactions, and depending on the one reaction the user selects, there is a different response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add all the needed reactions to the message:

```js
await sentMessage.react('emoji');
await sentMessage.react('emoji_2');
await sentMessage.react('emoji_3');
// ... //
```

Now, you need to edit the `filter(reaction, user)` function. `reaction.emoji.name === ''` means that the collector will only respond to one emoji - . If you want the collector to respond to different emojis, you can just delete this expression. In this case, the collector will respond to any emoji. But, you can also make the collector respond to a specific list of emoji:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => ["emoji1", "emoji2", "emoji3" /* ... */].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot
// the collector will now respond to all the emoji in the array
```

And finally, to display the user-selected emoji instead of , replace the string in `message.channel.send()`:

```js
message.channel.send(`You reacted with ${collected.first().emoji.name}!`);
```

Also, I can offer you 2 more optional things to improve the code:

1. Since the code is written specifically to collect one reaction, the `MAX_REACTIONS` constant probably won't change. So you can get rid of it and use `1` when creating the collector.
2. Because you do not pass the `time` property when you create the collector, the collector will last indefinitely if the author of the command does not choose a reaction. Therefore, you can pass the `idle` property and specify the time in milliseconds when creating the collector. After the specified number of milliseconds of inactivity, the collector will stop. For example:

```js
const collector = sentMessage.createReactionCollector({
    filter,
    max: 1,
    idle: 10000 // the collector will stop after 10 seconds of inactivity
});
```

If the collector stops due to inactivity, `reason` will be `"idle"`, inside `collector.on("end", ...)`:

```js
collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
    if (reason === "limit") {
        return message.channel.send(`You reacted with ${collected.first().emoji.name}!`);
    } else if (reason === "idle") {
        // ... //
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks this works like a charm! but instead of the "return message.channel.send(`You reacted with ${collected.first().emoji.name}!`);", is there a way i could send different embeds based on the selected emoji? like maybe
\n
 if( emoji === ) {
\n
message.channel.send(embed: [frogembed]);
\n
}else if (emoji === ){
\n
message.channel.send(embed: [snailembed]);

Comment: @SreyasMenon, Yes, you can do that. There is an example in my answer. `collected.first().emoji.name` is the emoji that the user has chosen. You should only use this line inside `if (reason === "limit") { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? I tried this but it only sending message for the reaction that is clicked 2nd.
`if(collected.first().emoji.name === ''){
            return message.channel.send('Froggo');
        } else if(collected.first().emoji.name === '') {
            return message.channel.send('Snailer');
        }`
Note: This is inside the if (reason === 'limit') like you said.

Comment: @SreyasMenon, I don't really understand what your problem is. Using the code you specified, you will get 'Froggo' if the user selects  and 'Snailer' if the user selects .

Comment: as an example, lets say i clicked frog. then nothing would happen. but after that if i click snail, it says snailer. it only gives response for the reaction that is clicked second

Comment: @SreyasMenon, No. Using your code, the corresponding message will be sent immediately. You most likely did not follow my instructions carefully and made mistakes.

Comment: Can you take a look and check if the code has any problems? Heres an image link:
https://imgur.com/a/aklDxzq

Comment: @SreyasMenon, send me the whole code. Not as an image, but as text. You can use [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com) for this

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JMGiH2hU

Comment: @SreyasMenon, Most likely, you are clicking too fast on the reactions. If the bot has not yet had time to put all the reactions to the message, and you click on the one it has time to put, nothing will happen. You will have to click on that reaction again after all the reactions are loaded, because only then will the collector start.